# time off of work" or "time off work"?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

Is it "time off of work" or "time off work" without 'of'?

Ex: I need to take some time off (of) work next month.

Comment: off of is not wrong, but colloq.

Answer (score 0):

"Time off" is leisure time

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/time+off

The verb we usually use with it is "Take", making the phrase "take time off". The rest is optional [ of work, from work, etc. ]

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @kns. Can you substantiate your answer in some way? How would the OP know if *your* opinion carries weight, if it were opposed to mine?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that I need to take some time off **from** work